# Dynamic selection of dates based on current month - select list

Tags: javascript, php, select, dynamic

I am trying to create, rather than using datepicker, an options list of the 1st days of the month (i.e. previous months 5, next months 2)

Given now is APRIL, this would be 01/04/2019 (dd/mm/yy)
So the option list would span, December 2018, up till June 2019, of each 1st of the month. Example would be as below, and then using a for loop to display the options

```
var previous = mktime(0, , 0, date("m")-5  , date("d"), date("Y"));
var current = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y"));
var next = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+2  , date("d"), date("Y"));
```

Hope is it not to vague of a question, thank you for the help

Comment: what problem did you run into?

Comment: Well tried outputting, but could never get it to work, so would have nothing showing on the list drop down. Is my theory of getting the dates correct & just output being my issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward in PHP using [relative formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

An example is:

```
$timenow = strtotime('first day of',time());

echo "\n";
for ($i = -5; $i < 3; $i ++) {
    $new = strtotime("$i month",$timenow);
    echo $new ," <-- ",strftime('%Y-%m-%d ',$new),"\n";
}
```

This uses 'first day of'

> 'first day of'
>   Sets the day of the first of the current month. This
>   phrase is best used together with a month name following it.
>   "first  day of January 2008"

And '*number space* unit'

> number space? (unit | 'week')
>   Handles relative time items where the value is a number.
>   "+5 weeks", "12 day", "-7 weekdays"

If you want to do it in javascript, suggest internet search for "js relative date".

Comment: Thank you Dino - will check this out and get back to you :)